# INSERT into the table and return id of the record Supabase JS

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

Based on the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/insert), inserting a new record

```js
const { error } = await supabase
  .from('countries')
  .insert({ name: 'Denmark' })
```

returns

```js
{
  "status": 201,
  "statusText": "Created"
}
```

For columns that are `Is Identity`, it automatically assigns a sequential unique number to the column.

How to get the ID of the newly inserted record on Supabase with JavaScript client?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can add `.select()` after your insert statement in order to get the newly inserted record.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('countries')
  .insert({ name: 'Denmark' })
  .select()
```

You will see the inserted record inside `data` variable. Note that retrieving the inserted record requires you to have not only insert permission, but select permission on RLS policies.

On a side note, you can click on the buttons on the right of the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/insert) to view different use cases. You can see this example on `Create a record and return it` example.
[image: Supabase docs]

Comment: I've been using select() but gives me row level security issue, only skipped by using {returning: 'minimal'}. I'm using v.2

Comment: @Richi Double check your supabase-js version. `{returning: 'minimal'}` does not exist in v2.

Comment: thanks for the comment @dshukertjr but only works for me if i disable rls

Comment: @Richi That probably means that the user does not have the appropriate permission via RLS for performing the action. In order for the user to be able to insert and select the data, they need both insert and select permissions. Make sure they do have the permission, and if you are still hitting a wall, I would suggest you to create a separate question providing the RLS policies you have set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you needed this:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('countries')
  .insert({ name: 'Denmark', {returning: 'minimal'}})
```

With this the data will only contain the `id` of the created country.